# R ggplot2 ticks only between facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the facetting in ggplot. My question is: how is it possible to draw ticks between facets? I am aware of the `scale = "free_y"` option which gives ticks and values:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + facet_wrap( ~ cyl, scale = "free_y")
```

But only ticks?
This is basically what I want:

[image: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/seaborn-FacetGrid-1.png]

Comment: Just erase the `scale` argument so the facets share x and y axes.

Comment: thanks. but erasing the scale argument will also erase any ticks from the y-axis of right-hand plots and I want to keep them.

Comment: You may want to consider a `grid` solution and make separate plots with tight margins.

Comment: thanks. Grid is one option, but I prefer facets cause its more suitable regarding the sizing of my plots (when they have different extent). Is there any solution by using facets to draw the example in the figure above?

Comment: What you ask can be done, but your code snippet uses `facet_wrap` whereas the diagram suggests `facet_grid`. They will require different solutions.  Do you know which one you will use?